# Google Maps SDK v1.1.2 for iOS demo doesn't work?

Tags: ios, maps, demo, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm using the current version 1.1.2 of Google Maps SDK for iOS.
1.i added apikey.
2.Compiled successfully, 
but can not run.i can't see anything.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyIHs.jpg

Anyone who has achieved to make it work?
http://lwxshow.com/google-maps-sdk-v1-1-2-for-ios-demo-doesnt-work

Comment: Are you sure you followed all the steps in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start?

People often miss adding -ObjC in the Other Linker Flags section.

Answer (score 0):

It has worked without a hitch in my case, just need to follow the "Getting started" instructions carefully. Have you added all the required frameworks to the build phase?. See here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start#adding_the_google_maps_sdk_for_ios_to_your_project

What emulator/iOS SDK version are you running? You need iOS SDK 6.0 or later for development.